# Installing js file using npm

Tags: javascript, npm-install

I am trying to install .js package using npm but I am getting an error about the repository right in git.
This is the command.

```
npm install -S apiconnect-cli-logger/logger.js
```

and I am getting the following error

[image: error]

Comment: Use "npm install -S apiconnect-cli-logger"

Comment: why in particular logger.js is unaccessible. @deshak9

Comment: by the way it worked.. Thanks @deshak9

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install from file system point to an absolute or relative path that contains a package.json file

```
npm install -D ../foo
```

If you sre installing from git use the https url you would use for clone

```
npm install -D whsthever.git
```

Take a look at the docs:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install